# scala parser failure: string literal expected

Tags: string, scala, parsing

help please! What I'm doing wrong? Should I use RegexParsers?

```
object Working extends App {

  class Parser(string: String) extends StandardTokenParsers {

    def value: Parser[Any] = numericLit

    println(phrase(value)(new lexical.Scanner(string)))
  }

  new Parser("123")
}
```

returns: [1.4] parsed: 123

```
object NotWorking extends App {

  class Parser(string: String) extends StandardTokenParsers {

    def value: Parser[Any] = stringLit

    println(phrase(value)(new lexical.Scanner(string)))
  }

  val p = new Parser("asd")
}
```

[1.1] failure: string literal expected

asd
^

What does he want?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals should be enclosed in quotes. The following lines would work:

```
val p1 = new Parser("'asd'")
val p2 = new Parser("\"asd\"")
```